# stuck with a problem

Tags: android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class costom extends Activity implements OnclickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Nearbyhome.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;}
    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View Button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

is showing a problem   "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (costom)"

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo , OnclickListener , it should be OnClickListener , 
You might not have imported the packages , press ctrl+shift+o if you are using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class costom extends Activity {

    private MyOnCLickListener implements View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v){
          switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
            Intent i = new Intent(costom.this, Nearbyhome.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
          }
      }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View Button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
    }
}
```

And Java Style Convention advises you name your clasess with first capital letter as 'Costom' instead of 'costom'

Answer (score 0):

I am not the worlds best Android programmer but have just finished writing my first Android app, I would potentially look at doing it as follows,

```
 public class Mainscreen extends Activity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);//Sets where the image view is located
    final Button Wordsearch_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Wordsearch_button);//Declares the usage of a button
    Wordsearch_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {//waits for the button click
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent next1 = new Intent();//when clicked it goes to the new intent i.e the java code Wordsearch_Action
            next1.setClassName("android.solver", "android.solver.Solution2");
            next1.putExtra("message_variable", "message"); 
            startActivity(next1);  //starts the new intent

        }

    });       
}
```

Hope that helps you solving your problem.